# Determining if a user account has a password set/enabled on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi

In my app, i am checking if a user has a password set/enabled on Windows as part of a security app(vulnerability scanning).

I myself come from a software development background thus i am fairly new to new when it comes to system administration. So far im aware of of the **LogonUsers** API which works but using this API and attempting to "login" will empty credentials counts towards the account lock policy if set thus making using the API impracticable.

A cmd command i recently discovered, `net use \\%COMPUTERNAME% "/user:%USERNAME%"`, works "sometimes" but more often than not it would not be able to check if there is a password set as it produces the same output.

In the program Bit defender Internet Security, the vulnerability scanning utility has a check to do just this question with high accuracy **without** triggering/counting towards the "failed login attempts" counter when the Group Policy Account lockout policy is set. I tried using Sysinternals process monitor to reverse engineer this functionality but could not find anything(its possible I missed something). Another puzzle is figuring out how Bit defender is capable of getting the password "length".

I was wondering if anyone has any advice on checking if a user account has a password set/enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Once the password has changed, even windows does not know what the length of the password is. The password are stored as fixed length hash in the SAM database. There are undocumented APIs to query the SAM database to get the password, but it essentially only returns the hash of the password which is fixed length.

You can retrieve the various information about the password policy using [NetUserModalsGet()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netusermodalsget) api, but that will only return the minimum password length, etc. There is another api to get information about user account called [NetUserGetInfo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netusergetinfo) and that will return password age and maybe you can use that to check when the password was last changed, but it may not be of much help. One way to do this would be to call LogonUser using blank password and if it failed, reset the bad_pw_count to what it was before your attempt. In any case, I guarantee you that any program that claims to know the length of the user password in windows is bullshit.